# Finding filenames containing version numbers in C#

Tags: c#

I have file names with version numbers embedded, similar to NuGet's naming scheme. Examples:

```
A.B.C.1.2.3.4.zip
A.B.C.1.2.3.5.zip
A.B.C.3.4.5.dll
A.B.C.1.2.3.6.zip
A.B.C.1.2.3.dll
X.Y.Z.7.8.9.0.zip
X.Y.Z.7.8.9.1.zip
```

Given a pattern "A.B.C.1.2.3", how do I find all those files and directories that match, regardless of version number? I support both `major.minor.build.revision` and `major.minor.build` schemes.

That is, given "A.B.C.1.2.3", return the following list:

```
A.B.C.1.2.3.4.zip
A.B.C.1.2.3.5.zip
A.B.C.1.2.3.6.zip
A.B.C.1.2.3.dll
A.B.C.3.4.5.dll
```

Bonus points for determining which file name has the highest version.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question to specify a given version.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/15464440/232574, but use a filter like `.Where()` to iterate your collection of filenames

Comment: @NickStrupat sorry, i miswrote my question. `Contains()` is trivial and not what I'm after. I need to recognize semantic versioning in filenames.

Comment: I would go with regular expression and capture the numbers in named groups in order to compare the overall versions.

Comment: @helb I found this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/maxhauser/semver/master/Semver/SemVersion.cs and it looks promising

Comment: @MarkRichman Indeed, Comparing the versions once they are parsed is not trivial either... Have a go with what you found.

Comment: @jdweng No. You need to extract the semantic version from the file name. Splitting on periods doesnt tell you what substring represents a version.

Comment: @jdweng How would you parse "Dummy.2.Lib.1.2.3" ?

Comment: See my latest answer below.

Comment: See my answer, it extends jdweng's solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31926058/3825611

Comment: A lot of answers here, how did this turn out?

Answer (score 2):

If you know the filenames end with the version, you could `Split` the filename string on `.`. Then iterate backwards from the end (skipping the extension) and stop on the first non-numeric string. (`TryParse` is probably good for this.) Then you can `string.Join` the remaining parts and you have the package name.

Do this for the search term to find the package name, then each file in the directory, and you can compare just the package names.

Comment: The problem is having to support semantic versioning. That is, `Some.Human.Readable.Name.1.2.3.ext` or `.1.2.3.4.ext`

Comment: How is that a problem? Isn't that just additional logic on top? Once this process is over, you have the numeric parts as a result of going through each array element.

Comment: Won't work if you have Some.2.File.3.Thing.3.4.5.zip. The last 3 or 4 places are what represents the semantic version.

Comment: I agree with @31eee384. In that example, you would stop stepping backwards once you reached "Thing". So the version would be 3.4.5

Comment: But since you break on the first non-numeric entry (iterating backwards), you get `Some.2.File.3.Thing` as the package name. I actually made this answer in response to @Helb's comment "How would you parse "Dummy.2.Lib.1.2.3" ?"

Answer (score 2):

Credits to jdwweng for his answer as well as 31eee384 for his thoughts. This answer basically combines both ideas.

First, you can create a custom class like so:

```
class CustomFile
{
    public string FileName { get; private set; }
    public Version FileVersion { get; private set; }

    public CustomFile(string file)
    {
        var split = file.Split(".".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        int versionIndex;
        int temp;

        for (int i = split.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (!Int32.TryParse(split[i], out temp))
            {
                versionIndex = i+1;
                break;
            }
        }

        FileName = string.Join(".", split, 0, versionIndex);
        FileVersion = Version.Parse(string.Join(".", split, versionIndex, split.Length - versionIndex - 1));
    }
}
```

Using it to parse the filename, you can then filter based on it.

```
string[] input = new string[] {
    "A.B.C.D.1.2.3.4.zip",
    "A.B.C.1.2.3.5.zip",
    "A.B.C.3.4.5.dll",
    "A.B.C.1.2.3.6.zip",
    "A.B.C.1.2.3.dll",
    "X.Y.Z.7.8.9.0.zip",
    "X.Y.Z.7.8.9.1.zip"
};

var parsed = input.Select(x => new CustomFile(x));
var results = parsed
    .Where(cf => cf.FileName == "A.B.C")
    .OrderByDescending(cf=>cf.FileVersion)
    .ToList();
```

In this example, the first element would have the highest version.

Comment: Why `internal set;`, instead of `private set;`? Otherwise, nice! Didn't know `string.Join` had that overload.

Comment: It should probably be private. I tend to use internal out of habit, but in this instance I think private is better. I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] input = new string[] {
                "A.B.C.1.2.3.4.zip",
                "A.B.C.1.2.3.5.zip",
                "A.B.C.3.4.5.dll",
                "A.B.C.1.2.3.6.zip",
                "A.B.C.1.2.3.dll",
                "X.Y.Z.7.8.9.0.zip",
                "X.Y.Z.7.8.9.1.zip"
            };

            var parsed = input.Select(x => x.Split(new char[] { '.' }))
                .Select(y => new
                {
                    name = string.Join(".", new string[] { y[0], y[1], y[2] }),
                    ext = y[y.Count() - 1],
                    major = int.Parse(y[3]),
                    minor = int.Parse(y[4]),
                    build = int.Parse(y[5]),
                    revision = y.Count() == 7 ? (int?)null : int.Parse(y[6])
                }).ToList();

            var results = parsed.Where(x => (x.major >= 1) && (x.major <= 3)).ToList();

            var dict = parsed.GroupBy(x => x.name, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            var abc = dict["A.B.C"];
        }
    }
}
​
​
```

Comment: Looks close, but the A.B.C. bit is arbitrary. So hard coding the indexes won't work. Also, the build could contain 3 or 4 elements, depending on the type scheme.

Comment: Ah, I see the revision bit now.. Nice. However, the name could be This.Is.The.File.Name.1.2.3.4. Using your code, the filename would be This.Is.The

Comment: Don't guess what the size of the filename is.  Let Mark decide.  It can easily change the size of the name array by using Take(x) where x is based on the size of the split array.

Comment: Update answer to make a dictionary.

Comment: Use the filename: "A.B.C.D.E.1.2.3.4.zip" and see what I'm talking about. y[0], y[1], y[2] only takes the first 3 strings, when it should take 5. Also, if it were "A.B.1.2.3.4" it try to take 3 when it should be taking 2.

Comment: The take number is Take(X - 5), where x is the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regular expression like in example below

```
    var firstPart = Console.ReadLine();

    var names = new List<string>
    {
        "A.B.C.1.2.3.4.zip",
        "A.B.C.1.2.3.5.zip",
        "A.B.C.1.2.3.6.zip",
        "A.B.C.1.2.3.dll",
        "X.Y.Z.7.8.9.0.zip",
        "X.Y.Z.7.8.9.1.zip"
    };

    var versionRegexp = new Regex("^" + firstPart + "\\.([\\d]+\\.){1}([\\d]+\\.){1}([\\d]+\\.){1}([\\d]+\\.)?[\\w\\d]+$");

    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        if (versionRegexp.IsMatch(name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            foreach (Group group in versionRegexp.Match(name).Groups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Index {0}: {1}", group.Index, group.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Good, but the "A.B.C" part is also arbitrary.

Comment: What is the general rule for file name? It should contain version part and start with arbitrary letters?

Comment: You can add the first part to your version regex dynamically. Answer was edited

Comment: You also can use Groups property to parse all version parts like numbers

Comment: Don't know the first part ahead of time. Just the full name including the version.

Answer (score 0):

This works using only LINQ, assuming the file name itself doesn't end with a digit:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "A.B.C.1.2.3.4.zip",
                                        "A.B.C.1.2.3.5.zip",
                                        "A.B.C.3.4.5.dll",
                                        "A.B.C.1.2.3.6.zip" ,
                                        "A.B.C.1.2.3.dll",
                                        "X.Y.Z.7.8.9.0.zip",
                                        "X.Y.Z.7.8.9.1.zip" };

var groupedFileNames = names.GroupBy(file => new string(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)
                                                         .Reverse()
                                                         .SkipWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.')
                                                         .Reverse().ToArray()));

foreach (var g in groupedFileNames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key);
    foreach (var file in g)
        Console.WriteLine("    " + file);
}
```

Comment: Won't work if you have `Some.2.File.3.Thing.3.4.5.zip`. The last 3 or 4 places are what represents the semantic version.

Answer (score 0):

you can use new Version() to compare versions like this:

```
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
            fileNnames.AddRange(new[] {
                "A.B.C.1.2.3.4.zip",
                "A.B.C.1.2.3.5.zip",
                "A.B.C.3.4.5.dll",
                "A.B.C.1.2.3.6.zip",
                "A.B.C.1.2.3.dll",
                "X.Y.Z.7.8.9.0.zip",
                "X.Y.Z.7.8.9.1.zip" });

            string filter = "a.b.c";

            var files = fileNames
                //Filter the filenames that start with your filter
                .Where(f => f
                      .StartsWith(filter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                      )
               //retrieve the version number and create a new version element to order by
                .OrderBy(f =>
                    new Version( 
                        f.Substring(filter.Length + 1, f.Length - filter.Length - 5)
                        )
                );
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Calling .ToLower() and then using InvariantCultureIgnoreCase() is unnecessary. I would remove the .ToLower() bit

Comment: Close, but the input would be "A.B.C.1.2.3" or "A.B.C.1.2.3.4" not just the filter.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you can use Version class for comparison.
I believe function below can get you versions starting with certain name.
It matches the starting name then performs a non greedy search until a dot and digit followed by 2 or 3 dot digit pair and any character after.

```
public static List<Version> GetLibraryVersions(List<string> files, string Name)
{
    string regexPattern = String.Format(@"\A{0}(?:.*?)(?:\.)(\d+(?:\.\d+){{2,3}})(?:\.)(?:.*)\Z", Regex.Escape(Name));
    Regex regex = new Regex(regexPattern);
    return files.Where(f => regex.Match(f).Success).
            Select(f => new Version(regex.Match(f).Groups[1].Value)).ToList();
}
```